# Building a text editor. Reading character from terminal in raw mode

Tags: c, linux, terminal

I'm following the tutorial [Build Your Own Text Editor](https://viewsourcecode.org/snaptoken/kilo/03.rawInputAndOutput.html) on how to program your own text editor.

I am currently at the low-level keypress reading and mapping it to editor operations(Section: Refactoring keyboard input). But **when I implement the same** in my code and run it, **my terminal just freezes up** and I've to restart to get back to normal. I'm using Parrot OS(if that matters). Here is the relevant section of my source code:

```
char editorReadKey() {
    int nread;
    char c;
    while ((nread = read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1) != 1)) {
        if (nread == -1 && errno != EAGAIN)
            die("read");
        /*if (iscntrl(c))
            printf("%d\r\n", c);
        else
            printf("%d('%c')\r\n", c, c);
        */
    }
    return c;

}
void editorProcessKeypress() {
    char c = editorReadKey();
    switch (c) {
        case CTRL_KEY('q') : exit(0);
                             break;
    }
}
int main(void) {
    enableRawMode();
    while (1) {
            editorProcessKeypress();
    }
    return 0;
```

The functions **enableRawMode** and **disableRawMode** aren't different and more or less are the exact implementation of the tutorial.

```
void disableRawMode() {
    if(tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &orig_termios) == -1)
        die("tcsetattr");
}
void enableRawMode() {
    if(tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &orig_termios) == -1)
        die("tcgetattr");
    atexit(disableRawMode);
    struct termios raw = orig_termios;
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &raw);
    //turns off echoing the command on the screen
    //turn off cannonical mode
    raw.c_iflag &= ~(BRKINT | ICRNL | INPCK | ISTRIP | IXON);
    raw.c_oflag &= ~(OPOST);
    raw.c_cflag |= (CS8);
    raw.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ICANON | IEXTEN | ISIG);
    raw.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
    raw.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;
    if(tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &raw) == -1)
        die("tcsetattr");
}
```

Any reasons as to why that might be happening? Or am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT:** Added the return value to `editorReadKey()` which I had  somehow missed putting it here.

Comment: Start with `int c;` And probably you are using termcap or curses: at least add the relevant headers.

Comment: @wildplasser `int c;` - not this time

Comment: So what did you mean by "terminal freezes"? You've got the `ctrl+q` as the exit key there, did you press `ctrl+q`?!

Comment: @wildplasser already tried the same. The problem is still persistent.

Comment: `editorReadKey` needs to return a value.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Well, when I run the program my terminal freezes- in the sense- that it becomes unresponsive and I have to close the present terminal and restart it to get it back running. Even the ctrl+q seems to do nothing.

Comment: `char c = editorReadKey();` expects a value returned from the function, but as @kaylum points out, your current `char editorReadKey()` does not return anything.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala `case CTRL_KEY('q')` I was assuming he is using termcap or curses, which wrap the functionkeys to nos printable codepoints. [ yes: the `read(fd, &c,1)` suggests differntly...

Comment: Actually, it seems you have butchered the original tutorial code. `editorReadKey`  is essentially an infinete loop that consumes the input and does nothing with it. The original code checks for ctrl-q. You've moved that code out to be checked by the caller but the function never returns.

Comment: Regarding that **char editorKey()** returning a value. Yeah, I had returned the char in the original code. Somehow I had missed it here.

Comment: @kaylum I don't think so. It has simply been moved to `editorProcessKeypress()`. The switch case essentially does the same thing, doesn't it?

Comment: Yeah it does. As long as you actually return correctly in `editorReadKey`.

Comment: BTW, you really should use a debugger. Stepping thru the code would/should make the problem more obvious.

Comment: @kaylum I had specified the return value correctly in the original source code. It just somehow skipped here. Edited to make in clear.

Comment: @kaylum I am already debugging the source code as I type this comment. It's just that none of it seems to work.

Comment: Sorry, are you saying even with the `return` the problem still persists? What input are you typing in? Is it ctrl-q? What value does the debugger tell you that the function returns?

Comment: With a little tweaking to the source code, I was able to run the program successfully. But I don't know why the original source code won't run.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl-S</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-Q</kbd> are used to suspend and resume output to the console in cooked mode, which may explain your observations, although you disable this mode by turning off `IXON` in `raw.c_iflag`. The `VMIN` and `VTIME` settings might be incorrect too: setting `VMIN` to zero seems wrong.

In Quick Emacs, I use this code to set up the raw mode:

```c
    tcgetattr(fileno(s->STDIN), &tty);
    ts->oldtty = tty;

    /* input modes: no break, no CR to NL, no parity check, no strip char,
     * no start/stop output control. */
    tty.c_iflag &= ~(BRKINT | ICRNL | INPCK | ISTRIP | IXON |
                     IGNBRK | PARMRK | INLCR | IGNCR);
    /* output modes - enable post processing? */
    tty.c_oflag &= ~(OPOST);
    /* control modes - set 8 bit chars, no parity checking */
    tty.c_cflag &= ~(CSIZE | PARENB);
    tty.c_cflag |= CS8;
    /* local modes - echoing off, canonical off, no extended functions,
     * no signal chars (^Z,^C) */
    tty.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ICANON | IEXTEN | ISIG | ECHONL);
    /* control chars - set return condition: min number of bytes and timer.
     * We want read to return every single byte, without timeout. */
    tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;   /* 1 byte */
    tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;  /* no timer */

    tcsetattr(fileno(s->STDIN), TCSANOW, &tty);
```

A detailed explanation for the flags can be found at on he [Linux man page for termios](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html).

Comment: I appreciate the explanation. But I don't understand how `VMIN = 0` might be wrong here. I had set it to zero because I want the `read()` to return as soon an input is read. I must add, the code was working perfectly fine till I reached the `Refactor Keyboard Input` part of the tutorial and then it started behaving oddly. I don't get it as to why that might be happening.